# Apache Shutdown Unexpectedly - No Blocked Ports

Tags: windows, apache

I get the following errors:

```
3:21:15 PM  [Apache]    Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
3:21:15 PM  [Apache]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
3:21:15 PM  [Apache]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
3:21:15 PM  [Apache]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
3:21:15 PM  [Apache]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
3:21:15 PM  [Apache]    If you need more help, copy and post this
3:21:15 PM  [Apache]    entire log window on the forums
```

I've checked with netstat, and there's no programs blocking my ports.  I can't seem to find the issue.  Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run setup_xampp.bat from xampp folder. This should fix the problem.